# Optimizing apply()

Tags: r, apply

I would like to optimize the following code. Currently it runs around 0.085 seconds on a 2Ghz dual core machine with 2MB L2 cache, for M being a 2404 by 100 numeric matrix:

```
Rescale <- function( M = utility.mat){
  exp.M <- exp(M) 
  result <- apply(exp.M, 1, function(x) x/sum(x))
  result <- t(result)
  return (result)
}
```

I have tried replacing `apply()` with for loop, which gives about the same performance. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bout 6 times faster on my machine:

```
Rescale1 <- function(M){
    M <- exp(M)
    result <- M / rowSums(M)
    return (result)
}
```

I thought that maybe you could speed it up further by calling `.Internal(rowSums())` but it didn't work out. Although that could simply be because I'm not using it correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me 0.28 second on my machine.

Comment: Calling `.Internal` (not recommended in general!) would only help if the overhead of calling `rowSums` was large. Since you only call it once, it's pointless. And in R 2.15 there is now `.rowSums` which is much less hacky. Still doesn't help here though.